# Why does the ```is_assignable_v<int, int>``` and ```is_assignable_v<int&, int>``` have different result?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-traits

Why does the `is_assignable_v<int, int>` and `is_assignable_v<int&, int>` have different result? `is_assignable_v<int&, int>` returns true but `is_assignable_v<int, int>` returns false. It's not very intuitive.

`is_assignable_v` is `std::declval<T>() = std::declval<U>()` by definition from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_assignable).
That means, `std:declval<int>() = std::declval<int>()` return false but `std:declval<int&>() = std::declval<int>()` returns true.

`std::declval<int>()` is rvalue of int. Then what does `std::declval<int&>()` mean? If it means reference to rvalue int, then Is is possible reference to int without const can refer rvalue?

I totally confused about `is_assignable_v`.
Could you explain it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `std::declval<int>()` is rvalue of `int`. Then what does `std::declval<int&>()` mean?

Lvalue `int`, due to [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing).

For [scalar types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ScalarType), you can only assign to lvalues, not rvalues. For classes, you can by default assign to rvalues too, unless you intentionally prevent that.

Note that references can't be retargeted by assigning to them, instead this assigns to whatever the reference points to.

Also note that [expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1), so trying to assign to a "reference to `int`" is no different from trying to assign to lvalue (or rvalue) `int`.